# Part guidance: Switching 120 VAC @ 3 kHz in < 5 ms

Tags: ac, high-voltage, switching, high-frequency

I want to control electroluminescent wire, which runs at 100 Volts AC @ 1000 to 3000 Hz, with a desired switching delay of under 5 ms. I have used Sparkfuns products in the past, but they are no longer on offer, and cheap replicas from China do break a lot. So I am looking to explore alternatives, if they exist. I feel like the voltage and frequency is a rather untypical workload, so I have difficulties searching for appropriate components, and I am looking for help.

What components could I use to create a circuit that switches said voltage, concurrently, to several channels?

Are there any kind of relays that fit this purpose?

Is there a single component, that can replace the circuit on the EL Escudo Dos, for example, i.e. an optcoupler, a triac, and a couple of resistors in between. Soldering this myself is hardly managable.

The application is wearables, so I am working with 12 VDC max, and I have an inverter to create the AC.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: When you say 120VAC you’re referring to the high frequency high voltage drive for the EL wire? I ask because 120VAC conjures up Wall socket power for me.

Comment: Yes, 100 VAC, at about 1500 Hz, depending on how much wire is connected to it. If there was another way to create the AC signal from the inverter, or multiple ones, then that could also be an option...

Comment: Gating the inverter (turning it on or off) would seem the easiest to me as you wouldn’t be switching high voltages. This could be as simple as adding a transistor and resistor to each inverter and an microcontroller could drive this easily. Exactly how to do that depends on the actual inverter.

Comment: Right, the problem with that is I need multiple inverters, and those are bulky and heavy. This is for wearables. I have at least 8 channels.

Comment: Where is the problem with triacs or two antiparallel SCRs?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and probably cheapest option might be MOSFET output optocouplers, such as the [TLP240](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TLP240GA_datasheet_en_20230525-1102049.pdf). It can handle 400 V and 120 mA, and is around a dollar in production quantities. It can be driven directly from a microcontroller with 3 mA and a limiting resistor.

Or maybe an [EL lamp driver](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/mic4827-1891139.pdf).

And maybe look into display drivers for gas plasma or electroluminescent displays. http://www.bitsavers.org/components/national/_appNotes/AN-0084.pdf

Comment: I think this is pretty much what I was looking for, I also discovered "triac output optocouplers" during my own research as well, and already ordered a couple MOC3043.

Comment: I have tried this now using MOC3043, but the problem is that the wire isn't switching off, when I turn off the control signal...

Answer (score 0):

It’s really not a hard problem. Two mosfets in series can switch each wire. Switching will be several orders of magnitude faster than 5ms without trying hard.

The frequency of the AC doesn’t matter all that much. A triac would work for this too I’m sure, and would be easier to drive.

If you can get a 150V DC source then one half of an H bridge can turn it into AC and if both are off, the wire is off. Connection to the wire via series capacitor. With a full H bridge no capacitor would be needed. Such H-bridges are everywhere for motor control so finding them in IC form shouldn’t be hard I’d hope.

Alternatively, one half of an H-bridge can be shared for one end all wires. Then you only need N+1 half-bridges to drive the whole thing from DC.

Comment: The pplication is wearables, so a 150 V power source is out of question. I do have a 12 V DC-to-AC-inverter that I am currently using.